# How can I add different views to each list item using navigation destination in this swift app?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this example app model and I show it on a list inside the new "NavigationStack" modifier and link the list items with the "NavigationLink"...
[image]

my question here is I have different files with different view for each item list and I need to navigate from each list item to a different view using "Navigation destination" modifier but I can't figure out how...

If any one can help...

I think I should use if-else or switch but I don't know how...
[image]

Comment: Use this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/  in particular the
 `Navigate to different view types`.

Comment: Code should be included as code not an image.

Answer (score 3):

What if you have a Fruit struct like:

```
struct Fruit: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let kg: Int
    let type: FruitType
}

enum FruitType: String {
    case banana = "Banana"
    case orange = "Orange"
    case apple = "Apple"
}
```

And then use the fruit type to determin the destination like:

```
  NavigationStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(fruits) { fruit in
                        NavigationLink(fruit.type.rawValue, value: fruit.type)
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: FruitType.self) { type in
                    switch type {
                    case .banana: Text("Banana!")
                    case .orange: Text("Orange!")
                    case .apple: Text("Apple Inc.")
                    }
                }
            }
```

I also suggest having the navigationDestionation modifier attached on the List, not ForEach